# Who deletes previous nlohmann json object resources when value is replaced?

Tags: c++, json, memory-leaks, nlohmann-json

I have a key and I want to change the value of the key with another json object.

```
   json newjs = ...;
   json tempjs = ...;
   newjs["key"] = tempjs["key"];
```

What will happen to the data existed in `newjs["key"]` previously?

Will nlohmann class automatically destroy it or is it a memory leak?

OR do I need to manually erase the key first and assign as above?

Comment: Don't know about nlohmann's jason implementation. But to begin with, it probably performs copy on data from "key" during the assignment. Generally, classes in C++ need to manage their resources on their own without user's interaction. I highly doubt that such a popular library has bugs in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally it's a kept by an "*`ordered_map`: a minimal map-like container that preserves insertion order*".

The actual standard container used in this `ordered_map` is a `std::vector<std::pair<const Key, T>, Allocator>` and the assignment you do is performed via

```
    T& operator[](const Key& key)
    {
        return emplace(key, T{}).first->second;
    }
```

where `emplace` is defined as:

```
    std::pair<iterator, bool> emplace(const key_type& key, T&& t)
    {
        for (auto it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it)
        {
            if (it->first == key)
            {
                return {it, false};
            }
        }
        Container::emplace_back(key, t);
        return {--this->end(), true};
    }
```

This means that `operator[]` tries to `emplace` a default initialized `T` into the internal map. If `key` isn't present in the map, it will succeed, otherwise it will fail.

Regardless of which, when `emplace` returns, there will be a `T` in the map and it's a reference to that `T` that is returned by `operator[]` and it's that you then copy assign to.

It's a "normal" copy assignment and no leaks should happen.

Comment: Is this true even if the structure of previous value and new value completely different?
Each key has a two level subkeys internally

Comment: @InQusitive Yes, the `json` object you assign to will be responsible for freeing it's own internal allocations and there is no manual memory management anywhere inside nlohmann/json so leaks are highly unlikely. There is only one place in the library where a `unique_ptr` `release()`s its internal pointer - but it looks really well guarded.